# Unable to get push (remote) notification when app icon tapped

Tags: ios, background, apple-push-notifications, payload

According to the [Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW4), when a remote notification is delivered and you tap the app icon in the SpringBoard:

> The user taps the default button in the alert **or taps (or clicks) the app icon**. If the default action button is tapped (on a device running iOS), the system launches the app and the app calls its delegate’s application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method, passing in the notification payload (for remote notifications) or the local-notification object (for local notifications).
>
> If the notification is remote, the system also calls application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:.

However, when I see the remote notification badge and I tap the app icon, neither `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` (app would be running in background), nor `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`, nor `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` are called...

I successfully get the push notification's payload when tapping a banner or an alert, how could I also get it when tapping the app icon?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to continue reading.  The remainder of the section you quoted reads -

> If the app icon is clicked on a computer running OS X, the app calls
>   the delegate’s applicationDidFinishLaunching: method in which the
>   delegate can obtain the remote-notification payload. **If the app icon
>   is tapped on a device running iOS, the app calls the same method, but
>   furnishes no information about the notification.**

Note the section I bolded.  The short answer is that if the application is launched from the app icon then no information is provided about any notifications that may have been received.

Comment: Thanks... then is it not possible to get the payload in such scenario? I want to show a text related to the push I received when the app goes to foreground, and it is possible when user taps a banner or an alert, but what if user is only seeing badges?

Comment: Standard practice is to check the server for any data that may have been pushed - I don't know whether this applies in your case

Comment: And could enabling Background Mode for Remote Notifications solve this scenario?

Comment: Only in the case where your app is still running in the background. If your app is terminated then the push is not delivered to your app

Comment: Paulw11, how do you recommend configuring the server, do you suggest keeping a table with push notifications sent, querying on every standard app icon tap boot, and then marking them as received when you receive them or process them? This seems like allot of pain for something they already provide on OSX

Comment: Normally the push is just a notification that some other data has changed;new messages for example, and so you just check that data.  If it were messages, you check the number of unread messages and update the badge accordingly.  The push notifications themselves aren't important and may not even be delivered as push notifications are not a guaranteed delivery

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same issue and unfortunately like Paulw11 said, your app will receive no information on the payload. However! I have noticed that the badge number will reflect the missed notitfication, so on app launch you can check if your `applicationBadgeNumber != 0` and if it is not, you can query your server for the last data that was sent.